# React Table - open in new tab?

Tags: hyperlink, tabs, react-table, right-click

I am using React Table any I'm trying to open each row in a new tab (each row has an id associated and should lead to /path/:id) but only when I right click -> open in new tab. I don't want to use _target='blank' Basically I want to make each cell into a link. Currently I am using getTdProps like this:

```
          getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
            return {
              onClick: (e) => {
                if (rowInfo) {
                  History.push(`/vehicle/${rowInfo?.original?._id}`);
                }
              },
              className: `${rowInfo && "cursor-pointer"}`,
            };
          }}
```

This basically turns my cells into buttons and this is not what I want.
The only solution I came up with is something like this:

```
      Cell: ({ original }) => (
        <Link to={{pathname:`/vehicle/${original?._id}`}}>
          <Battery percent={original?.battery_level}
        </Link>
      ),
```

The issue is I have to use this for every column. The project is quite big and I have a lot of tables. Is there a better way to target all the cells and make them into links so I can right click -> open in new tab?

Comment: Why don't you use the `a` tag for this purpose?

Comment: a or Link is pretty much the same. I was just wondering if I can somehow target all the cells, so I don't have to fill my code with a href = ...

Comment: Are the hrefs you intend to end up with exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, they should look the same.

Comment: It would actually be ideal if I could wrap the entire row in a href or Link to, not just the content of the cells. This way, everywhere the user right clicks he can open in a new tab.